# Symfony 3, RESTAPI, PUT, fileupload

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm adding RESTFull api to my site, and i need to update my tools, where are pictures witch need to be updated too.
My problem is like that for PUT request

```
/**
* @Rest\Put("/tools/{id}")
* 
* @param Request $request
*/
public function editToolAction($id, Request $request)
```

symfony is only parsing data with `Content_type` `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so i can get it from request, and this is working for strings etc.

```
$parameters = $request->request->all();
```

but to send files i need header to be:

```
content-type:"multipart/form-data; boundary....

$parameters = $request->request->all();
$files = $request->files->all();
```

but for multipart header i'm getting nulls for both `parameters` and `files`

for @Rest\POST this is working perfectly

im not working on client side so i can't change request from PUT to POST, any ideas how to fix it ?

site is using symfony 3.4. , php 7.2. , FOSRestBundle, FOSOAuthBundle,.... to check if it is working Postman was used

Answer (score 0):

PHP will automatically parse `application/form-data` for you and place the result in `$_FILES`. Symfony likely just reads from that super global to populate the result of the `->files()` function.

However, PHP will only do this for `POST` requests. Since you're using `PUT`, PHP won't parse it, and Symfony will likely not expose it.

If symfony doesn't have a userland implementation of an application/form-data parser, you should find one on composer.